# Why don't I see a CPU usage monitor in menu bar on my raspberry Pi 4? And how can I get one?

Tags: cpu, monitoring

I cannot seem to find anyone asking about this or talking about this... I'm very new to computers and don't know much at all so any help would greatly be appreciated.

So I have a raspberry pi 3b+ and it has a cpu usage monitor in the toolbar at the top of the screen that I thought could be useful for me to see on my new raspberry pi 4 b 4gb... but I noticed I don't have one on here and cannot find any info online about this... PLEASE Help this NOOB.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

There is a CPU Usage Monitor which you can activate in the Panel.

Whether it is useful on a Pi4 is doubtful.

Right click on the Panel then the Add button and select from the list.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on task bar and select Add/Remove Panel items.
In panel preferences window highlight Menu. Click on Add.
This opens the Add plugin to panel window.
Scroll down to CPU Usage Monitor and highlight. Click on Add.

You can highlight CPU Usage in the Panel Preferences window and click on up or down to change the position on taskbar.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/132582)